# Uncaught ReferenceError: error_message and succes_message not defined- codeigniter(datatable) delete button

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, datatables, crud

I am using codeigniter CRUD. I am showing the view using datatable by setting the theme in crud

```
 $crud->set_theme('datatables');
```

The delete button is not working when the theme is 'datatable'.
The error message is:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: success_message is not defined
at Object.success (datatables.js:213)
at j (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2)
at x (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:4)
at XMLHttpRequest.b (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:4)
```

I tried defining $dialog_forms from list_template.php, but it didn't work. can you help me? thank you

Comment: You should probably add the `datatables` and `jquery` tags. Someone had the [same error here and includes answer.](https://www.grocerycrud.com/forums/topic/4079-undefined-success-message-on-delete/)

Comment: yes, i saw it but his answer did not work with me. i found another answer and immediately shared it. thank you anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried something and it worked! I wanted to share it with you since I could barely found people writing about it.
I changed into the file  themes/datatables/js/datatables.js (delete_row() function).
I replaced

`success_message(data.success_message);`

with this

```
$('#list-report-success').slideUp('fast');               
$('#list-report-success').html(data.success_message);
$('#list-report-success').slideDown('normal');
```

it worked